# Running the app on a real Apple Watch and infinite spinner

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I wanted to make a clickable prototype of an app on (storyboard only). I have just added two interface controllers and some images and buttons. I filled xcassets with several images (overall less than 150kB) and tried to run the app. When there was a single interface controller with 3 buttons (images in background) + 1 imageView (around 100kB all) it took some time but the app lauched. I added 1 more interface controller and a few images to it (the biggest are around 9kB) and this time Xcode displayed me a message that it lost a connection with an iPhone but the watch is still running or the watch app timed out error. At the same time I have the app name on the watch screen and a spinner. And it's spinning for ages without any result... I've tried to delete the app from both devices, restarting, cleaning folders etc. and no success. Is there a limit of images one can put in the watch's xcassets? So frustrating...

Comment: You should not use the `watch` flag but the `apple-watch` flag.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing same issue where spinner on real devices was never ending.
This was because `watch extension` and `watch app` were missing `arm64` architecture, make sure you select `Standard Architectures(armv7 and arm64)`in build setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do/check:

- You should use the `xcassets` that is located in your WatchKit app, not the one in your WatchKit extension.
- Build and run your main iPhone app as the primary target once.

Comment: I use xcassets located in my WatchKit. I haven't checked your second tip but so far I have found a solution which works but is bit annoying. It looks every time I want to make a new build (even if there are little or no changes to the app) I have to: delete the app from both devices, restart both devices, clean & clean build folder and restart xCode...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, i've been struggling with this too...

the only way i found  : i click on digital crownd of the AppleWath, then re-tap on my app and magically the app launching (and the debugger work.)

if this is not working the hard way : Reboot xcode, Clean, if still not working same as you clean, restart devices... this is so annoying.

first solution take less time, and work 7/10 times

if someone knows a beter solution i'll take it !! ;-)